# Display field from one section in another section

Tags: templating, sections, category

I have two sections:

- Games
- Publishers

Games has a field called "GamesPublisher" that is a relation (field type "Entries"), the Source is "Publishers".

In my template to show an entry from games, I want to display the default field "title" of a publisher that I assigned to the games entry in the admin CP.

```
{% extends "_layout" %}
{% set title = "Games" %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('games').limit(10).order('title') %}
{% block content %}
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>
            {% for category in entry.GamesGenre %}{{ category.title }}{% endfor %}: <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a> (***Put Title of Publisher Here***, {{ entry.GamesReleaseYear.format('Y') }})
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

The place I want to insert the publisher's title is shown as:
***Put Title of Publisher Here***

Thanks all. I just started using Craft about 3 hours ago for the first time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but, give it a try:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}
{% set title = "Games" %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('games').limit(10).order('title') %}
{% block content %}
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>
            {% for category in entry.GamesGenre %}{{ category.title }}{% endfor %}: <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a> {% set publishers = entry.GamesPublisher %}{% for publisher in publishers %}({{ publisher.title }}{% endfor %}, {{ entry.GamesReleaseYear.format('Y') }})
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

If need be, have a look at [An introduction to relations and reverse relations in Craft CMS, with examples](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/introduction-to-relations-and-reverse-relations-in-craft-cms-with-examples)

Comment: Congrats! You won the line length competition against @user1513427

Comment: Yes, works like a charm. You saved my project!

Comment: Not how I would have done it but, when in Rome.

Comment: @Natetronn, how would you have done it?

Comment: Oh, don't listen to us. Do it how your team (or you) prefers it. That said, I might have added a bit more whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines etc.) Check out to the docs to better understand [what happens to your whitespace in Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control) and how to control it, if need be.